# Comma separated MYSQL CONCAT from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

How to you group concat 2 simple tables so the the output is:

```
John | One, Two
Luke | One, Two
```

I have seem some other examples, but I don't appear to make sense of it. Im a complete NOOB

users table

```
|name|names|
|John|001|
|John|002|
|Luke|001|
|Luke|002|
```

servers table

```
|id|name|
|001|One|
|002|Two|
```

MYSQL statement

```
SELECT *
FROM users 
INNER JOIN servers 
ON users.names = servers.names
```

Produces:

```
John | One
John | Two
Luke | One
Luke | Two
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` as follows:

```sql
SELECT u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(s.name ORDER BY s.id) names
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN servers s ON s.id = u.names
GROUP BY u.name;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Some tweaking, but you have put me on the right track. Thanks

Comment: Another question, why would some of those GROUP_CONCAT elements (one, two, etc,) be limiting the amount outputted? (some are quite large. About 270 records, but it only lists 75

Comment: I can only answer based on data actually shown (which I have done above).  You should either reveal the actual question, or maybe ask a new one in a separate thread.

Comment: Not to worry. I edited the group_concat_max_len variable in MYSQL, all show fine now. Thanks Again